# Как отобразить только выбранный метод доставки на странице checkout Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать что бы на странице оформления заказа checkout в месте выбора доставки отображался только выбранный способ доставки на предыдущей странице?

В корзине человек выбирает способ доставки
[image: выбор доставки]

На странице оформления отображаться только выбранный способ доставки
[image: отображение доставки]

Я так понимаю должен использоваться хук какой-то. Перерыл очень много статей, но не чего не нахожу.
Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию и правильной настройке WooCommerce должен выводиться только выбранный способ доставки. У Вас что-то не так настроено или не корректно работает.